# Conclusion for global stability according to local stability

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

Say we have a non-linear system. The system has an equilibrium point at $0$. Say that we linearize the system around the equilibrium point. The transformed linear system comes up to be unstable. From that we can conclude that the equilibrium point at the initial (non-linear) system is also **locally unstable**. Does being locally unstable mean that the equilibrium point is also globally unstable?

Comment: It depends on your definition of *globally unstable*. If it means the system is not globally stable, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @Miguel It means the equilibrium is globally unstable.

Comment: This is an odd statement, as an equilibrium point is always a local point in the state space, which has either stable or unstable properties. Globally unstable is not often used in stability theory. If there is no point in the state space or manifold towards a system converges, then you just say the system is not stable.

Comment: @Giannis Words are not rigorous enough to do mathematics, often different books have different definitions and, as other comment mentions, this is not a common definition, and probably not much useful either. So we can only answer your question if you give us the precise mathematical definition of globally unstable equilibrium.

Comment: @seaver ahhh... sorry! I meant asymptotically stable! not globally. My bad.

Comment: @Giannis I'm not sure whether I understand the question now, haha. If the linearization around the equilibrium point is *not* stable, the equilibrium point of the NL system is not stable. If the real parts of the eigenvalues of the A matrix of the linearization are *all* strictly negative, then the equilibrium point is locally asymptotically stable. If the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues are nonzero, it is often called a spiral attractor.